# How can I unlock  the whole city on the PC version?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I would like to play the entire city without playing through the game, I only play for sentimental reasons (for the good old days). I would like to unlock the whole city, and there is no "cheat code" for this.

I won't play multiplayer or do any other thing with this. I only play single player once in a while.

So is there a cheat engine that lets me use the entire map? 
or a game I could download and load?

I'm using steam to run GTA!

Comment: this is the windows version. (there is a mac version as well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto:_San_Andreas)

Comment: I tried the same methods on a firends cd version and there everything worked perfectly. I guess that the saved games only work on the original games that aren't from steam.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no cheat that unlocks the entire map. You could however:

- Explore the map with a plane, (enabling the "Lock Wanted Level" cheat to make the Cops not chase you).
- Use a Savegame from someone who has unlocked every area. This is probably the easiest method. It shouldn't be that hard to find a save on the Internet.
- Create a Savegame like you want it to be with a [Savegame Editor](http://www.thegtaplace.com/downloads/f3456-gta-san-andreas-save-game-editor). I haven't tested it myself, but you should be able to create one relatively easily using that.

Comment: [This site](http://www.gtasavegames.com/savegames/San_Andreas) looks like it's got some good ones - you can take one with 100% completion, or start from earlier in the game if you so choose.

Comment: the save game is awesome! I can change **almost** everything! I can't edit the "accomplished missions" (I've set it to complete, but I still get a level 4 star if I go anywhere, where I'm not allowed to. And the "fog" in the map is still there.

Comment: As i said, i haven't tried the editor. Haven't played GTA SA since years. Maybe you want to use the "Lock Wanted Level"-Cheat to keep the cops away. Dunno which type of gamingstyle you are on to

Comment: I want to "free play" the game so I want to be able to buy every house and so on. so just getting rid of the cops spoils the point...

Comment: When you type **AEZAKMI** you will lock your current stars and wont increase the stars you have. So, do it with zero stars and the cops won't chase you. Here is the link to the cheat if someone else needs it on console or something: http://www.supercheats.com/video/Grand+Theft+Auto%3A+San+Andreas/123/videos.htm

Comment: you are missing my point, I want to play the game, but with everything unlocked... the game editor was the solution, if you select where you want to start as a "first" safe house, then you will be granted to go there, and buy more houses. thanks! :D

Comment: Fine! Have fun then dude :]

Comment: Why don't you use the save-game editor to bring yourself to each mission where you unlock a new area, complete only that mission, and rinse and repeat? For example, complete the one where Tenpenny drives you out to Angel Pine (can't remember anything else about that mission) and you've unlocked the San Fierro district.

Answer (score 7):

Did you consider downloading a save-game that has all the missions complete? You will also find plenty of save-games with each mission complete here:

http://www.gtasavegames.com/savegames/San_Andreas

Since there is no character customization in this game, I would personally not mind downloading and playing, if it's just for nostalgia :)

Comment: the problem is when I load the "100% done" game I start at the begging with the bike, and still have all the missions to go through! so it doesn't work. Sorry! :(

Comment: I got none of them working, as soon as I loaded them the game started from the beginning. But thanks for trying! :)

Comment: Sure, I wonder why your game is behaving like that. Maybe you should ask a new question about this bug, probably something to do with your PC setup. Also, are you sure you are placing the save files in the right directory?

Comment: it's in the correct directory I can see them in game and load them, but when I load them I just start from the beginning. my pc setup is windows 7 and I'm playing via Steam.

Comment: @Alvar The link in this answer goes to the GTA3 saves - you're playing San Andreas, correct?  The San Andreas page is linked from my comment on the other answer.

Comment: aaagh I somehow mixed up GTA3 with San Andreas - so sorry Alvar!

Comment: Okay, just updated the link to the proper place - thanks for the heads up agent86

Comment: I've tried the San Andreas files as well, they don't work. :)'

Comment: this works perfectly ona GTA version that's not from STEAM. Just so everyone knows.

Comment: "Since there is no character customization in this game" - there is customization, but nothing irreversible.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to edit a saved map with the [GTA San Andreas Save Game Editor](http://www.thegtaplace.com/downloads/f3456-gta-san-andreas-save-game-editor) and change my "first safehouse" to different areas, and then go ahead buy a new one and then just change my first safehouse again and do so. This made me be able to own every house in the game, this was the result I was after. I just hoped for a faster and easier result. But thanks everyone! :)

I haven't got the final part of the map working. When I enter the monstertruck at one of my "girlfriends" workshop the game just crashes. So I guess there is a problem with my method on unlocking the whole map.

so the outline is ***It sort of works.***

Comment: How did you edit a saved map?

Comment: @galacticninja with the software in the accepted answer.

Comment: I see. I edited your answer to mention this.

Comment: @galacticninja thanks! :) The point of my answer was mostly to show how it worked in the end, and it wasn't small enough for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is pretty old by now but another option, (I'm not 100% sure if it removes the barricades or the wanted level) is to start a new game, then while you're in the cutscene where you're in the back of the police car enter the spawn jetpack cheat. Then when they kick you out of the car instead of spawning normally you'll get the "wasted" message and spawn at the Los Santos hospital. From there you're free to explore and or play the game as normal with the exception that every door is unlocked (including some mission specific ones).